# Setting Queue Item Title

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a dialog workflow that creates an instance of a custom entity that is queue enabled.  I then create a queue item and reference this instance but I want to set the Title of the Queue item so that it is descriptive in the default view.  However when I go to set the Title field in the 'create' step, it is non-interactive.  I can't click on it, edit it or do anything with it.  I have made sure the title field is not read-only and I have compared all of the 'titles' field settings to another field (the queue item) and all the properties are the same between the two.  Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem. Can you explain? Some settings are not available before you save the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can't modify the field. The title of a queueitem will be set through the referenced activity.

If you take a look at the [queueitem metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309545.aspx#att) you will see that the attribute `title` is marked with

```
attribute | ... | IsValidForCreate | ... | IsValidForUpdate 
title     | ... | False            | ... | False
```

This means that although you could technically edit and write this field, the system will not allow it and filter this information out.

So basically you would have to set the title of the referenced activity to a descriptive value.

Comment: Thanks.  This explains a lot.  Extremely silly implementation on the part of Microsoft.  The custom entity I am working with doesn't have a title so this way of implementing things is short sighted IMO.  So is there some documentation about what the field must be named in order for the Queue item to auto-populate?  Some queue items (mail) don't have a title and somehow still end up getting assigned correctly (queue item uses the subject as the title).